# gdrive not working on Fedora 35

Tags: terminal, executable, google-cloud, google-drive, google

I would like to access my cloud data on Google Drive from terminal, so I have downloaded `gdrive` [from this source](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/releases); I have selected

```
gdrive_2.1.1_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

since I am on Fedora 35 with a 64 bit architecture, running a modern AMD processor (Ryzen 5). I unpacked the `.tar` file, and then I tried to execute the "gdrive" executable **but simply nothing happens!** I have never experienced something like this on linux. When I try to double click on the executable nothing happens, if I try to run it from shell with `./gdrive` it tells to me that the file does not exist, but it is there! I can see it with `ls` for example. The output of `file gdrive` is the following:

```
gdrive: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64,
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
interpreter /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1,
Go BuildID=LPNobKoNhYeFlz7JNx15/ZzI595Tul2vzANCybCLW/ivWdAFQEgsxk2IW4xm0E/km1nogdaurkNF26-P4f4,
not stripped
```

So it should be an executable that I can run! *What is going on?*

Comment: `chmod +x gdrive`. Running random binaries from the net is a good way to get your system powned.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov But when I looked at the file's properties I saw that the file was allowed execution! Why do I need to add the `+x` then? (and also: do you think `gdrive` classifies as a "random binary from the internet? It is a famous github project... Do you think I should be more careful?")

Answer (score 1):

```
ldd gdrive
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce41b2000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => not found
```

The binary doesn't use standard libc (glibc), it uses musl libc implementation.

`sudo dnf install musl-libc` fixes the issue.

Comment: Or install GoLang and compile from source with `go get github.com/prasmussen/gdrive`, which will use the native libc on your machine.